# ArcGIS Pro Legend Range Display

Tags: legend, arcgis-pro

When creating graduated color legends, other than manually formatting value ranges under the symbology legend label, is there any way of automatically showing the full numeric value range in the legend rather than the less than or equal to upper value range?

Comment: I think the short answer is no. May be you should suggest it as an idea over on the geonet website?